# How can I programatically determine if an IIS site is receiving requests?

Tags: c#, iis, wmi

The title pretty much says it all. Some caveats are:

- I need to be able to do it in C#
- It needs to be able to be done from a remote server (ie, running on one server, checking IIS on another)
- Needs to be close to real-time (within 1 second)
- Can use WMI calls

I've tried watching the log file, but it turns out that isn't nearly close enough to real-time.

Thanks!

EDIT: I put this in a comment on Tom's answer, but it's more visible here:

I was able to look for changes using this counter:

```
var perf = new PerformanceCounter("ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727", "Requests Total", "_LM_W3SVC_[IIS-Site-ID]_ROOT", "[Server-Name]");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about reading the ASP.NET requests/sec performance counter on the remote machine?

The System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter class has a constructor which takes a machine name.

Comment: I was able to look for changes using this counter:


            var perf = new PerformanceCounter("ASP.NET Apps v2.0.50727", "Requests Total", "_LM_W3SVC_[IIS-Site-ID]_ROOT", "[Server-Name]");

Thanks!

Comment: this what i need, but how to use this ?  what i need to see if the IIS up or down ?